# Why are potential electrolytes poor conductors in the pure liquid state?

Tags: electrochemistry

In my textbook, "In the pure liquid state, a true electrolyte is a good conductor of electricity. In contrast, a potential electrolyte is a poor conductor in the pure liquid state."
 definitions
"A true electrolyte consists of ions in the pure state. Most salts are true electrolytes. A crystal of NaCl, CuSO4, or MgS consits of positive and negative ions."
"A potential electrolyte consists of uncharged molecules in the pure state, but when dissolved in a solvent, it reacts with the solvent to some extent to yield ions"

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question. If a potential electrolyte (the term sounds strange to me, but whatever) in the pure state consists of uncharged molecules, then how would it conduct electricity?

Comment: I read it more that it was uncharged(not an ionic crystal) but when you put it in water, it becomes an electrolyte. Compared to true electrolytes, NaCl which has ionic structure and is electrolyte.

Comment: Geez, you heard about covalent compounds dissociating after being mixed with water, didn't you? If they aren't dissociated earlier, they don't conduct. Provide yourself example

Comment: @Mithoron How about bubbling CO2 through water? You'd end up with an acidic solution, which will be more conductive than pure water, by adding a neutral compound. I have to say though, I don't really understand the question either.

Comment: @SeanDoris Well, OP's asking about liquids so rather acetic acid. And answer would be probably: because they don't autodissociate strongly.